org-mode odt export not working in emacs 29
After upgrade to ubuntu22.04 and emacs29, the export to odt fails with :
org-odt-export-to-odt: OpenDocument export failed: Symbol’s function definition is void: loop
Any idea what is missing ?

Please do M-x toggle-debug-on-error, try the command again and add the resulting backtrace to your question.

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function loop)
(loop for comment in (reverse (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'comment 'identity)) do (let* ((v (let ((idx (or 0 ...))) (let* ((parray ...)) (if parray (let* ... ...) (let* ... ...))))) (v (let ((idx (or 4 ...))) (let* ((parray ...)) (if parray (let* ... ...) (let* ... ...)))))) (cl--set-buffer-substring v v "")))

Please cut and paste backtraces into a code block (delimited by triple backticks) in your question. They are too long for comments in general and they are unreadable as comments. But in this case, I'm guessing you need to (require 'cl) - e.g. with M-: (require 'cl) RET.

That did it thanks!

I’m voting to close this question because OP just needed to require cl.el. Q is likely a duplicate to others for undefined symbols because the defining library wasn't loaded.

@Drew: I don't agree with the reason for closing (that the question is not suitable for this site). If there is a duplicate (which is likely), we should find it and close it as a duplicate. I'll try and do that.

@NickD: Yes, of course that's better.
